Extracting equation/formula of drain current for the circuit model
I have simulated this circuit model in LTspice. Now I want to do an experimental fit for the graph for transient analysis of Id. Can anyone help me solving this circuit for Id? Or give me an alternative on how to do the experimental fit?


Where is your .model statement for your PMOS?
